# Python - TypeError: argument must have one "Write" method

Tags: python, csv

Hello this my code:

```
def update_thing():
        stud_ID = str(ID_num.get())
        stud_name = str(name.get())
        stud_course = str(Crs.get())
        stud_year = str(Yr.get())
        replace = stud_ID +','+ stud_name +','+ stud_course +','+ stud_year
        empty = []




        with open(file_op, 'wb') as fop:
            Swriter = csv.writer(file_op, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for row in fop:
                if row[0:9] == stud_ID:

                    Swriter.writerow([empty])
                    Swriter.writerow([replace])
                    msg = Label(upd_win, text="Updated Successful", font="fixedsys 12 bold").place(x=3,y=120)
                if not row[0:9] == getID:
                    msg1 = Label(upd_win, text="Updated Failed", font="fixedsys 12 bold").place(x=3,y=120)


        fop.close()
```

This code replaces the row it finds via ID number. So if it finds the ID number, it replaces those rows by emptying it and writing the newly inputted rows. However I'm having a problem with an error on the line

```
Swriter = csv.writer(file_op, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

it has an error: TypeError: argument must have one "write" method. I really don't know why I'm getting this.

```
file_op
```

is the filename which I got from the values inputted in the GUI. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `fop.close()` is unnecessary, by the way

Comment: I think you want to pass `fop`as the first argument to `csv.writer()`, instead of `file_op`.

Answer (score 1):

You open "fop" file, but trying to write to "file_op"

You need to have it like this:

```
with open("your filename string", 'wb') as file_op:
            Swriter = csv.writer(file_op, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```